# Why does it hover?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm creating my first website and I cannot get around this problem, my H3 link keep hovering below my third content list, does anybody know how to get around this problem, I'll be really glad If anyone can help me out

```
body {
    width:98.8%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
    text-align : left;  
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BARUK/8/)

Comment: Not quiet getting what you are trying to achieve here also you are using `position: absolute;` <-- this is really unexpected

Comment: Not sure what you are looking to do. I am even more confused after seeing the JSFiddle

Comment: What is your third content list?

Comment: There are three anchor elements with the text ENTRAR. Only one is visible, the other two are hidden behind the 2nd and 3rd image. So the problem is that each anchor element is not displayed inside the corresponding ´<article>´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm interpreting the comments correctly, I think you want what's happening in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BARUK/1/).

The issue was that the parent anchor tags of the `h3` didn't have any positioning, so I removed the `top` and `left` position on the `h3` and put that styling on the `a` tag. This is all on lines 27-37 of the CSS in the fiddle.

I think the bigger issue is that the `position` property is being used in a lot of places and ways that are not ideal.

Comment: This really worked, Thank you and to all of you guys, I started it learning in Codeacademy and I don't have somebody to tell me how thing go, so I'm super messy at the moment with my coding.  Thanks again